# How to rename files by batch?

Tags: files, file-management, media-files, productivity

I use OI file manager, but I would like to know if there is a way to remove spaces from file names and replace them with underscores, preferably in batch mode?

I would even be willing to perform this operation on my windows laptop, so this isn't specifically an Android question, though I'd prefer to do this on my phone. I'm a graphic artist and I have thousands of inconsistently named images in various places, and I'd really like to avoid doing this manually, one by one, as it would take months!

Comment: You may want to look at [this question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387780/); you can do this on Windows with a simple batch. Alternatively, there are a lot of bulk rename programs for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible with [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), though I cannot give you the "complete recipe". Basically, you could create a task like this:

- *Execute Command:* `ls -1 /path/to/your/files`, and capture the output into a variable
  <sup>the command will list all files in the given directory, one file per line</sup>
- Work on the variable. There are possibilities to convert it into an array, so you can use a `for` loop to handle each file
- again with variables, you can setup the rename command (e.g. using *Variable Search Replace*) in a new variable. Pseudo-Code: `mv "$old_name" "$(s/ /_/,$old_name)"`

---

But it is much easier to use a simple shell script in some terminal app (or via `adb shell`) to achieve the same:

```
cd /path/to/your/files
for file in $(ls -1); do mv "$file" "$(echo $file|sed 's/ /_/g')"; done
```