# How to move and rename all files from subdirectories to current directory?

Tags: file-management

I have a folder that looks somewhat like this:

```
Course
  Lessons 1
    a.mp4
    b.mp4
  Lesson 2
    c.mp4
    d.mp4
```

I would like the end result to be this:

```
Course
  1. a.mp4
  2. b.mp4
  3. c.mp4
  4. d.mp4
```

I managed to achieve some minor success using [LADB's app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.draco.ladb) and executing a [bash script](https://superuser.com/questions/355891/move-all-files-from-subdirectories-to-current-directory), but this is not practical since I always have to re-run the app.

Are there any simpler solutions?

Comment: You question is...odd. I mean what exactly are you looking for? A terminal app where you can run shell script? Or some AI that magically knows the pattern you need?

Comment: I am looking for suggestions to how someone experienced with Android would approach this situation. Although I assume it was sarcasm, the latter would be nice. It's doable with tensorflow, but I have no clue how to work with Android nor its possibilities. My knowledge is limited to apps like Tasker.

Comment: Besides, you didn't even mention when do you want anything to happen. Are you looking for some way to monitor a directory, so that when a directory pops up inside, all the files are moved out? [Edited by Firelord ♦]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I have to second Tom Yan's comment, though perhaps with a clarification: it looks like you already have a solution (running bash script from an app). Are you looking for [tag:automation] instead (like [How to rename files by batch?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58676/44325) using Tasker), or something like a one-click runnable script? Is the folder fixed or dynamic? Is it expected to run on any folder?

Comment: You need to think of triggers first. Under what conditions do you want files to be moved, and to which directory? The conditions can be defined in an automation app such as MacroDroid or Tasker or Automate, and actions can also be defined there. None of these apps need ADB access for doing that.